# Create spark function which accepts key ,value as argumets and return back RDD[string]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to create a  function which can later be used by three different RDD data sets.
Function takes key and value and converts to seq[String]

```
def ConvertToMap2(value: RDD[(String, (String,String,String,String,String,String))]): Seq[String]  = {
  value.collect().toMap.values.toSeq.map(x => x.toString.replace("(","").replace(")",""))
}
```

when I tried to apply by one data set its ok because it has one key with  6 values example:-

```
val StatusRDD=ConvertToMap(FilterDataSet("1013").map(x => ((x(5)+x(4)),(x(5),x(4),x(1),x(6),x(7),x(8)))))
```

but I tried to apply on another data set I need to we write the function because other data set contains 7 values with one key this makes to re write the function with same logic but different name.

```
def ConvertToMap2(value: RDD[(String,(String,String,String,String,String,String,String))]): Seq[String]  = {
  value.collect().toMap.values.toSeq.map(x => x.toString.replace("(","").replace(")",""))
}

val LuldRDD2=ConvertToMap2(FilterDataSet("1041").map(x => ((x(5)+x(4)),(x(5),x(4),x(1),x(6),x(7),x(8),x(9)))))
```

Is there a way to write one function for both which accepts 6 or 7 values of string with just one key ? or can I extend my function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TupleX` classes inherit from `Product`, so I would define the function like this:

```
def convertToSeq(rdd: RDD[(String, Product)]): Seq[String] = {
  rdd.values.map(x => x.productIterator.mkString).collect().toSeq
}
```

Note that `TupleX` classes have a `productIterator` that I'm using here to create the string (I found your way somewhat verbose and more difficult to read) and I'm also delaying the `collect` call until after converting the values, so the map operation is run in parallel.

Finially, I have changed the name of the function, since it converts to a `Seq` and not a `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

Yep go the answer need to use data type of any

```
def ConvertToMap (value: RDD[(String,Any)]): Seq[String]  = {
   value.collect().toMap.values.toSeq.map(x => x.toString.replace("(","").replace(")",""))
}
```